# Clarification regrading circular reference

Tags: javascript, circular-reference

I don't think I quite understand this concept.

I get how having stuff that require each other leads to a infinite loop but I don't see how this happens in some examples I view

```
function setHandler() {  
  var elem = document.getElementById('id')

  elem.onclick = function() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

How is this a problem? I just see a element being attached a function on click.

[image: Screenshot]

It says there's a reference through the outer LexicalEnvironment - but isn't this occurring once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"It says there's a reference through the outer LexicalEnvironment"* - What is "it"? (There is no error in the code you show, maybe you don't show enough code?)

Comment: @Tomalak http://puu.sh/9sURX/010cde7034.png

Comment: Ah, that's a bit clearer now. I've added the image to your question for reference.

Comment: @Tomalak—I don't think there is supposed to be any error, the OP just wants to understand circular references (presumably involving DOM elements, as there are others).

Comment: @RobG As far as garbage collection is concerned, the described situation *could* lead to a memory leak. I would assume that modern GCs are smart enough to figure this out, though.

Comment: @Tomalak
But why is a GC needed? Where is the circular reference being formed here, I'm just attaching a function to onclick through a function.

Comment: @Tomalak—yes, they *should* be clever enough, but IEs wasn't (in regard to circular references involving DOM objects at least) until some version of IE 6 mostly fixed it, and later versions seem to be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript uses something called lexical scoping. Scopes

- define what variables are visible in a certain context *(corollary: they define what variables are no longer visible to anyone and may be garbage collected safely)*
- are created for every `function` *(every time you use the keyword, a new scope is created)*
- can be nested *(because functions can be nested)*
- are persisted for every function *(when you call a function it is guaranteed that it can see all variables in all scopes (!) that were available when it was created)*

That means:

```
                                            // +- global scope
                                            // |
function setHandler() {                     // |+- scope for setHandler()
                                            // ||  sees: own, global
  var elem = document.getElementById('id'); // ||
                                            // ||
  elem.onclick = function() {               // ||+- Scope for anonymous function
    // ...                                  // |||  sees: own, setHandler, global
  }                                         // |||
}                                           // ||
                                            // |
```

Now the anonymous function you assign to `onclick` can see the variables `elem` and `setHandler` and everything from the global scope.

If the element is destroyed (removed from the DOM), the garbage collector considers what variables went out of scope. A less advanced garbage collector might do this by keeping a reference count for any in-memory object and clean up that object (free the memory) when the reference count reaches zero.

Now the anonymous click handler function cannot be cleaned up because it holds a reference to `elem` (via the scope) which in turn holds a reference to the anonymous function (via its `onclick` property). The reference count for both objects stays at 1 because the two refer to each other.

Note point 4 from above: Scopes are persistent, so the "lexical environment" of `setHandler()` is kept alive *even though* program execution has already left that function - because it is needed by the anonymous inner function. (This is called "closure" and is one of the cornerstones of JS.)

Modern garbage collectors can spot that situation and clean up the event handler appropriately, but notably old versions if IE misbehaved and leaked the memory.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a loop in execution, not one were memory was being cleaned so I couldn't figure out where the loop forms.

Comment: A *circular reference* has nothing to do with a loop. What you mean is "A calls B which calls A". This is usually called *infinite recursion* and the cause for stack overflow errors. This can happen with "A calls A calls A" as well, of course.

Comment: Yeah, pun not intended. :)

Answer (score 1):

> How is this a problem?

It was a major problem in early versions of IE 6 as it created "memory leaks" because circular references involving DOM elements led to memory not being released when a page was unloaded, so they consumed more and more memory, making the browser less responsive. There's a good article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-memleak/).

In regard to the particular pattern in the OP, the circular reference is easily avoided:

```
function setHandler() {  
  var elem = document.getElementById('id')

  elem.onclick = function() {
    // ...
  }

  // Break circular reference
  elem = null;
}
```

Comment: You could also make the variable global, the window object that holds globals is cleaned up at the end of the pages life cycle.

Comment: I understand why circular reference is a problem, I don't understand why the code I presented leads to one.

Comment: Because the listener on the element has a reference to the execution context of *setHandler*, which has the global object on it's scope chain, which has a reference to the element (e.g. through the ID), which references the listener.